# Mongoose - findByIdAndUpdate - doesn't work with req.body

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a problem with update documents in mongodb over mongoose.

My model bellow:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    first_name:{
        type: String
    },
    last_name:{
        type: String
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    is_active:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    last_login:{
        type: Date
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Controller put function bellow:

```
exports.updateUser = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.user_id, {$set:req.body}, function(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("RESULT: " + result);
    });
    res.send('Done')
}
```

Output on console:

```
Listening on port 3000... { first_name: 'Michal', last_name: 'Test' } 
PUT /api/users/54724d0fccf520000073b9e3 200 58.280 ms - 4
```

The printed params are provided as form-data (key-value). Looks that is not working at least for me any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: is this { first_name: 'Michal', last_name: 'Test' } your req.body?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use `req.params.user_id` instead `req.body.user_id`

```
exports.updateUser = function (req, res) {   
    console.log(req.body);

    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.user_id,{$set:req.body},{new:true}, function(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("RESULT: " + result);
        res.send('Done')
    });
};
```

Comment: you should add {new: true} to make it work. 
Docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake. Note that I'm calling

> req.body.user_id

where should be

> req.params.user_id

- url is `(PUT) http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/users/54724d0fccf520000073b9e3`

Answer (score 0):

Further, the `req.body` would have key value as Text and realized as `String` object, inside the code. Thus, it is useful to parse the string into JSON using `JSON.parse(req.body.user)` - while the `user` is the key and `{ first_name: 'Michal', last_name: 'Test' }` is the value.

```
console.log(req.body);
var update = JSON.parse(req.body.user);
var id = req.params.user_id;
User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, function(err, result){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("RESULT: " + result);
    res.send('Done')
});
```

Note: the **update** value is sent to Mongo DB as

```
{$set: { first_name : 'Michal`, last_name: 'Test' }
```

Further reference: [Mongoose JS documentation - findByIdAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)