# Mongoose won't update new field after updating schema declaration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I just noticed that when i update my schema definition and add a field, for instance "name: String" and then try to use

```
People.update( { _id: user_id }, { $set: { name: 'something' } } )
```

mongoose won't update my property.

I keep getting nModified: 0 on the response.

The only way i found to fix it, is to Drop the collection and then the new documents will work perfectly.

Am i missing something? Does mongoose somehow "caches" the schema of a collection on mongodb itself and then needs a "drop" in order to "reload" the properties?

Comment: No there is no storage within MongoDB of schema definitions. But if you set a property to a value that already exists mongodb will report 0 modified as there is nothing to modify. Also you say you are updating schema definitions, but are you restarting your application between changes? Have you enabled additional plugins not mentioned here. The best way to be certain is enable debuging `mongoose.set("debug",true). Then you will see if the method calls being sent differ to what you are calling. But check the other things first.

Answer (score 1):

Stop your node app and restart the app. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think findbyidandupdate will do the task for you. Try with this link

[Mongoose - findByIdAndUpdate - doesn't work with req.body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108177/mongoose-findbyidandupdate-doest-not-work-with-req-body)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your People model and also please use callback with update.

see below and works fine..

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var User = mongoose.model('User', { email: String, name: String });
//First added only email and used save to save the document.
//var user = new User({ email: 'john.due@example.com' });
User.update({ _id: '55fbbb268e7307dc0bf9ae92' }, { $set: { name: 'John Due' }}, function(err, result) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(result)
 });
```

Comment: It works fine when setting to a certain _id, but when setting it to "null" or "undefined" it didn't update for me. Update says nModified 0

Comment: after deleting the collection and creating it again it works, which makes me confuse and worried because i can't delete the collection on production.